# Same line working fine in a project showing casting error in another

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

I am using same line of java 8 code (copied from one to another), the code worked fine in the original project but in the second project it is showing List cannot be cast to List.Below is the line of code .I am using eclipse.

```
List<String> tmpArray = Arrays.asList(strWithTrailingDelimiter.split(delimiter))
              .stream()
              .filter(rec -> !rec.trim().isEmpty())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

These are the imports in the second project

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

The compile time error I am getting is :

```
    "type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>"
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: Are you perhaps importing the wrong `List`? It must be `java.util.List`.

Comment: Check your package imports.

Comment: What is the exact exception? When it is thrown? Compile time or run time?

Comment: I dont think is a importing issue, the ***java.awt.List*** is not generic...

Comment: Compile time exception is coming "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>"  .

These are the imports

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

Comment: That looks like a well known type inference issue of older Eclipse versions. Update Eclipse…

Comment: type of 'strWithTrailingDelimiter' is same in both project ?

Comment: Eclipse same in both the projects..using Neon.3

strWithTrailingDelimiter is a String in both the cases

Comment: It still looks suspiciously similar to [Bug 453422](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453422). Note that even within an Eclipse installation of a particular version, you can update the modules (like the compiler) individually. Look into the main menu `Help ‣ Check For Updates`…

Comment: By the way, instead of `Arrays.asList( … ).stream()` you can use `Arrays.stream( … )` in the first place…

Comment: If the different behavior (accept vs. error) happens when using the same installation of Eclipse (which exact version?), then we'd need more information about the projects. If you are able to isolate the problem into a fresh project, please file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT (component=Core). TIA